# Getting values from an HTMLCollection to a string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, htmlcollection

I am attempting to grab the selected values of a multi-select dropdown and convert them into a single string for later manipulation. At the moment I have the following code:

```js
    function newComic()
   {
    var elem = document.querySelector("#genreList").selectedOptions;
    var arr = [].slice.call(elem);
    var genres = arr.join(', ');
    window.alert(genres);
    }
```

```html
 <select id="genreList" multiple="multiple" name="addGenre[]"  style="width: 150px;font-size: 10pt;">
     <option value="Action">Action</option>
     <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
     <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
     <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
     <option value="Mystery">Mystery</option>
     <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
     <option value="Period">Period</option>
     <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
     <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
     <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
    </select></p>
                
                <p><input type="button" onclick="newComic()" value="Add Comic" id="btnAddComic" style="font-size: 10pt; width: 150px; height:40px;"></p>
```

The alert window is currently outputting the following:

[object HTMLOptionElement, object HTMLOptionElement, ...]

where '...' represents any further hypothetical options.

What I need is for 'genres' to output as, for example, 'Action, Romance, Thriller' instead.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you `join` the array, it is calling the "toString" of each element.  In this case, they are DOM elements and return their type.  You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) first to create a new array of strings containing the `value` of each option:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfx6r5sm/

```
var genres = arr.map(function(el){
    return el.value;
}).join(', ');
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved my problem entirely, with minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the selected items like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newComic(){
    var elem = document.querySelector("#genreList").selectedOptions;
    var arr = [];
    for(var x=0; x<elem.length; x++){
        // for the TEXT value
        //arr.push(elem[x].text);

        // for the value
        arr.push(elem[x].value);
    }
    var genres = arr.join(', ');
    window.alert(genres);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through HTMLCollection like this

```
<script>
    function newComic()
    {
       var elem = document.querySelector("#genreList").selectedOptions;
       console.log(elem);
       for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
           console.log(elem[i].attributes[0].nodeValue); //second console output
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think jquery is best suited for this task.

HTML

```
<select id="genreList" multiple="multiple" name="addGenre[]"  style="width: 150px;font-size: 10pt;">
            <option value="Action">Action</option>
            <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
            <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
            <option value="Mystery">Mystery</option>
            <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
            <option value="Period">Period</option>
            <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
            <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
            <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
</select>

<p><input type="button" value="Add Comic" id="btnAddComic" style="font-size: 10pt; width: 150px; height:40px;"></p>
```

jQuery

```
$("#btnAddComic").click(function(){
    var inz = $( "#genreList option:selected" ).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(',');
    alert(inz);
});
```

### SEE THE FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/inzamamtahir/1bm45gu7/2/

Comment: ofcourse that works. Have a look at the fiddle and confirm it too

Comment: on the fiddle, i see them all as one string with no spaces/separation between items, so it would be hard/impossible to tell between "no" & "palitos" and "nopalitios". i do like the simplicity though ;)

Comment: yes, you were right. There was no delimeter there that could show 2 words separately but I have not edited the post. It is fine now. Have a look please.