# for each option from select2 multiple, append option value text into div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append, jquery-select2

With a  I want to press a button, add the selected item (s) to a *div #list*

```
<select class="select2" multiple="multiple" name="string_items[]" id="string_items">
  <option>value i want to append</option>
</select>
```

move on from this:
    
 
to this (assuming that each item is a template using `.append ("<div class =" item ">" + option text + "</div>")` + the text that contains each )

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="item">appended value</div>
</div>
```

I am not an expert in JS but I have the idea of what I want. My JS code:

```
$("#post-button").click(function(e){
  var items_list = $('#string_items').val(); //combo box / <select id="string_items">

  //for each item {
    //var item_tpl = '<div class="item">'+ <OPTION> TEXT </OPTION> +'</div>';   //My simple but powerful template for this example
    //$("#list").append(item_tpl); //adding to #list div
 //}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

> The `for...of` statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in *String*, *Array*, Array-like objects (e.g., *arguments* or *NodeList*), *TypedArray*, *Map*, *Set*, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

```js
$("#post-button").click(function(e){
  var items_list = $('#string_items').val();
  for (item of items_list){
    var item_tpl = '<div class="item"><OPTION> '+item+' </OPTION></div>';
    $("#list").append(item_tpl);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select2" multiple="multiple" name="string_items[]" id="string_items">
<option>Value 1 to append</option>
<option>Value 2 to append</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="post-button">Post</button>
<div id="list">
    <div class="item">appended value</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, additionally I had to use .map () and return .text () because I forgot to mention that each <option> has a value attribute and your answer only returned the value, but with .map () then <option value = "instead of this"> returns this text </option>, just like in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29107900/8712160